# RbConfig::CONFIG alternative for Crystal-lang

Tags: ruby, crystal-lang

`RbConfig::CONFIG` is a good place to get all the platform information (OS, arch etc) at one place. Is there any such global object/ module present in Crystal-lang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few constants defined under `Crystal` that provide information on the compiler itself:

```
Crystal::BUILD_COMMIT
Crystal::BUILD_DATE
Crystal::CACHE_DIR
Crystal::DEFAULT_PATH
Crystal::DESCRIPTION
Crystal::PATH
Crystal::VERSION
```

As for the platform, you can rely on flags to check on which architecture you are using macros:

```
{% if flag?(:darwin) %}
  puts "From Mac!"
{% elsif flag?(:linux) %}
  puts "From Linux!
{% end %}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This definitely helped. But for my code I decided to rely on `uname`.